# Error in using android dataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, build.gradle

There is a problem when I enable dataBinding in app/build.gradle that gives me this error: "Error:Failed to resolve: support-v4". Below is the build file with dependencies and libraries:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dxhf.studio.databinding"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

I added the support-v4 but it didn't solve the problem and also there is no issue when removing the dataBinding part. What causes the problem?

**Update 1.**
This is my project level Gradle file.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()

  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please post your project level gradle file.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 it's updated.

Comment: Try updating your project level gradle file with this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` and see if it works

Comment: @parekhkruti26, it throws the "Error:Connection timed out: connect".

Comment: Post your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

Comment: @parekhkruti26, would you clarify what causes the problem?

Comment: This maybe the issue of android gradle plugin.

Comment: @parekhkruti26, I added 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2' as a test without enabling dataBinding, but it gives me the same error.